# How to load the datatable data via ajax?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have 1000 records in my table. But i want to get the each page data ie 10 records on demand(on page click). Because now i want to wait until the 1000 records load in the DataTable instead of that on clicking the each page the 10 records want to fetch from the datatable on each page visit Is there any features in dataTable for this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/arrays.txt"
    } );
} );
```

Comment: If you only have a small no. of records, you can just fetch all those 1,000 records, and let dataTable manage the paging in the client side. But if your data will grow more than this, you should shift to server-side processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to initialize table:
For example you have table id: example

```
var oTable =$('#example').dataTable();
```

then you can use jquery get or ajax. to insert in datatable you need to use .fnAddData() for example:

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
        $.each($.parseJSON(data),function(i,e){
            oTable.fnAddData( 
                [
                    e.id,
                    e.name,
                    e.gender,
                    e.state,
                    e.phone
                ]);             
    });
```